# django-viewflow, multiple flows within the same app causes url not unique via @rest.register

Tags: django-viewflow

Say I have an app called 'MRT`, inside the app I have 2 flow definitions.

`Flow_A` and `Flow_B`

both registered via `@rest.register` as below:

```py
@frontend.register
@rest.register
class Flow_A(Flow):
    ....

@frontend.register
@rest.register
class Flow_B(Flow):
    ....
```

When I `runserver`, it raises warning: `?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'viewflow_rest:mrt' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace`

The consequences of this is that causing tasks of one of the flow(depends on which one registered last) cannot be url reversed. eg. `Reverse for 'check_size__detail' not found. 'check_size__detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been rectified in v1.5.11

see github [ticket](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/issues/253)